# how to get Windows event logs in English though the default language is Spanish?

Tags: windows, logging, language, event-viewer

I want to analyze the windows event logs that is been getting generated from windows machines. The default language for windows is Spanish so it is generating the logs in Spanish but the tool which i'm using can be only used for English.

So is it possible to generate the logs in English even though the default language is Spanish.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you may try this third party software's [FULL Version](http://www.eventsentry.com/downloads/select-edition) / OR / [The Free Light Version](http://www.eventsentry.com/downloads/select-edition) called [EventSentry](http://www.eventsentry.com/).

> The framework also supports multiple languages, so if you open an
>   event on a Spanish Windows, then the event will display in Spanish (of
>   course assuming that the message file from the vendor supports that)
>   instead of English.

(changed french-to-spanish in the quote above)

[ [::: Answer-Source :::](http://www.eventsentry.com/blog/2008/04/event-log-message-files-the-de.html) ]

[ [::: Website Link :::](http://www.eventsentry.com/) ]

Comment: Alternatively, you may try a C++ script explained on [this stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777154/extract-eventlog-messages-in-a-specific-language)

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

Some of the components that implemented MUI is affected by the following key:
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\MUI\Setting\PreferredUILanguages]

The key is of type REG_MULTI_SZ which suggested that you can prepend "en-US" before your current language to see if it works for you. (Although I doubt any component that implemented MUI haven't implement en-US, which means all fallbacks after en-US is likely to be meaningless. For all the legal values of your system, see the ~\MUI\UILanguages subkey.

Since most of the Windows compoents have implemented MUI, after added/changed this key and reboot you should be able to see the event log language change for these subsystems. The setting will be read by whatever process implemented MUI on start and will not affect process that don't implement it.

Note that after you follow any of the solution here, you may experience problem when installing software that will update your performance counter. In such event please take a look at KB2480023 to fix the LCID in ~\MUI\UILanguages subkeys accordingly.

Comment: I do. In fact because my company install HKSAR version of Windows but I need English version of error message, I used this to make the eventlogger log English error message. (I do also install English version of language pack, and then apply the change to all users, but I don't think this will affect the system language)

Note that MUI settings are only loaded once during process startup, you'll want to reboot after changing it.

Comment: Why it would affect the system language? Afterall MUI is an independent subsystem for localization since WinXP. It doesn't affect process/thread UI culture settings.

Also, it's impled that if the registry setting doesn't support multiple value, it wouldn't be designed to use REG_MULTI_SZ type. If it doesn't accept multiple value, Microsoft would have been design it with non-sense.

Comment: The value that I have confirmed work is "en-US' as in the answer.

Honestly speaking, I believe my reply is precise "as is". It contains what you need to do, under what condition it'll have effect and so on. Prove whether it works or not is the responsibility of asker.

Comment: If you cannot update your answer, then I cannot reverse my downvote, your question could be improve but you clearly don't care to improve it.  I have deleted my comments since they clearly were not going to lead to an improved answer.

Comment: Okay, I'll update the answer.